# Spatio-temporal triple correlation

Tags: fourier-analysis, correlation

I would like to simplify if possible the spatio-temporal triple correlation of the following function:

$$f(\vec{x},t)=\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0(t)) \otimes f_p(\vec{x})$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta, $f_p$ is a generic function (i.e. a 2D Gaussian) and $\otimes$ represents the convolution operator.

I define the triple correlation as:

$$C(\vec{\xi}_1,\vec{\xi}_2,\tau_1,\tau_2):=<f(\vec{x},t)f(\vec{x}+\vec{\xi}_1,t+\tau_1)f(\vec{x}+\vec{\xi}_2,t+\tau_2)>_{\vec{x},t}$$

The spatial bispectrum of $C$ is

$$B_{\vec{x}}=<\hat{f}(\vec{k}_1,t)\hat{f}(\vec{k}_2,t+\tau_1)\hat{f}(-\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2,t+\tau_2)>_{t}$$

where

$$\hat{f}(\vec{k}_1,t)=\mathcal{F}\{f(\vec{x},t)\}=\mathcal{F}\{\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0(t)) \otimes f_p(\vec{x})\}=\mathcal{F}\{\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0(t))\}\mathcal{F}\{f_p(\vec{x})\}=\hat{f}_p(\vec{k}_1)\exp{(-2\pi i\vec{k}_1\cdot\vec{x}_0(t))}$$

Then it follows that:

$$B_{\vec{x}}=\hat{f}_p(\vec{k}_1)\hat{f}_p(\vec{k}_2)\hat{f}_p(-\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2)<\exp{(-2\pi i\vec{k}_1\cdot\vec{x}_0(t))}\exp{(-2\pi i\vec{k}_2\cdot\vec{x}_0(t+\tau_1))}\exp{(2\pi i(\vec{k}_1+\vec{k}_2)\cdot\vec{x}_0(t+\tau_2))}>_{t}$$

Is it ok until now? Could I do something more?
Thanks

Comment: Could you try to clarify your notation? Most of the terms are undefined (left to the reader's imagination). For example, you did not specify what the pedix $p$ in $f_p$ actually means. Who is $\delta$ (Dirac Delta function)? And what operation represents the Kronecker product's symbol? (convolution?)

Comment: @PseudoRandom Thanks for asking. I try to edit the question.

Comment: Is $\vec x$ a 3-dimensional vector or is it just 2D? $\vec{x}_0(t)$ needs clarification: what does it represent? Are you sure there isn't a typo somewhere in the first equation? The convolution is made with respect to time or with respect to space?